# How can I grab an element from the page source in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
html_source = driver.page_source

if "Sold Out" in html_source:
    return True
```

The following code returns True because there is an element with the text "Sold Out" in the source. How can I grab this element? Is there a way to grab its class or name to then use in driver.find_element?

Answer (score 1):

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Sold Out')]")`

Should work.

Comment: Could you give me some example code of how I could  use this line? When trying it in my program it is unable to find the sold out element even though it is there. And thanks for the help!

Comment: You got to share code and results, so I can point to the wrong part.

Comment: If i post the code in the comments it gets formmated horribly so where should I post it?

Comment: use nekobin.com, and share here the url, don't forget to add `.py` at the end of the URL so it will be formatted well.

Comment: If I replace the driver.find_element_by_class_name("fulfillment-add-to-cart-button") with your code then the program returns element not found. here is the website i am using as a test https://www.bestbuy.com/site/sony-playstation-5-digital-edition-console/6430161.p?skuId=6430161

Comment: I'm trying to get my program to be able to go into any website that contains a sold out button and pull out the element. Not by  class because not every website will have the same class for its button.